# Cucumber report is showing Given instead of And in console for cucumber with inteliij

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber-serenity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deVWt.png)

Cucumber report is showing Given instead of And in console for cucumber with inteliij as shown in image

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What exactly is your question? Please take some time to write the question.

Comment: Cucumber version/language/libraries being used? Sample project the issue can be reproduced with would be helpful

Comment: Thank you @PhaniRithvij and lena Actually after running cucumber file the steps where i have mentioned And was displaying as Given steps in console of intellij after updating the version but after going back to old version its working fine i think their is issue with new version of intellij

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your Given statements getting changed to And is you must be having something like this

```
Given I have send A                                                            
And I have send B                                                              
And I have send C
```

These all are Given statements only. So, latest version of Cucumber has changed all And to its corresponding  Given/When/Then Statement. This is not an issue, but a new feature. So, it should be something like this

```
Given I have send A                                                         
Given I have send B                                     
Given I have send C
```